# How to read, change and replace data with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make a gambling website simulation, and I need to have a variable that stores the user's balance. This will change when they place a bet.

The variable is called "userbalance" and it set at 500 on Firebase. The user's bet is successfully stored on firebase. Therefore, I need to restrive this bet value again, and take it away from "userbalance", therefore updating their balance.

```
function storewager(){
var coinref = firebase.database().ref();
var coinwager = document.getElementById("coininput").value;
var userbalance = 
coinref.child("coinbet").set(coinwager);
changeuserbal();
}

function changeuserbal(coinwager, userbalance){
    var balref = firebase.database().ref().child('userbalance');
    var coinwager = document.getElementById("coininput").value;
    var userbalchg = balref - coinwager;
    window.alert(balref);
    balref.child("userbalance").set(userbalchg);
}
```

I can't understand why it is working correctly in storewager, but not in changeuserbal.

Here's the firebase database layout:

```
gambling-website-simulationaddclose
     coinbet: "66" <--- this is the user bet, which is changed by storewager()
 userbalance: 500 <--- I'm trying to take coinbet away from this
```

Thank you very much for your help, as when I can do this, I should be able to progress a good amount more.

**EDIT**

I've now managed to send the variable value, not the name To "userbalance". However, the calculation isn't correct. I believe the issue lies with the original value of "userbalance" not being referenced correctly.

Therefore, "userbalance" is just the wager but minus.

**bal - coinwager = userbalchg** ---> this is uploaded to "userbalance"

**0 - coinwager = userbalchg** ---> This is what I think is occuring

Here's the updated piece of my code:

```
function changeuserbal(coinwager){
    var balref = firebase.database().ref().child("userbalance");
    balref.once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot){
    var bal = snapshot.child("userbalance").val();
    var coinwager = document.getElementById("coininput").value;
    var userbalchg = bal - coinwager;
    balref.set(userbalchg);
});
}
```

Comment: It's a little challenging to tell without being able to see your data structure. Please update your question to include that structure. Without it, my best guess is this: the code has `var balref = firebase.database().ref().child('userbalance');`, but then it assigns `userbalchg` as a child of `balref.child("userbalance")`, which implies that `userbalance` has a child key named `userbalance`. I imagine you just want `baler.set(userbalchg);`

Comment: Thanks for your help. userbalchg is a variable to calculate the new user balance. This is then uploaded to the database and replaces the value of userbalance. I believe I have now put up the data structure. If you need any more info please ask. I'll try and implement what you've suggested.

Comment: @JenPerson I've managed to correctly reference "userbalance", but it updates to "userbalchg" instead of the int value. Here's my new code, and thank you very much for your help:  
        `var balref = firebase.database().ref().child('userbalance');`
 `var userbalchg = balref - coinwager;`
 `var newbal = balref.set('userbalchdg');`

Comment: Right. Don't put `'userbalchdg'` in quotes because then you're just writing that string to the database instead of the balance itself.

Comment: @JenPerson Okay, I tried that and sadly still doesn't work :( appreciate your help though.

Comment: @JenPerson I've made some progress, and updated my post. Not to far away now from reaching a solution, but still experiencing an issue.